# Как изменить масштаб svg-картинки

Tags: css, вёрстка, svg

У меня есть svg картинка. У самого блока svg размер `width="64"` `height="64"`, но получившийся рисунок, который этот блок отображает, намного меньше размера `64 х 64`, и получается, если вставить этот svg-блок в какой нибудь родительский элемент, он займет слишком много места, а сам рисунок будет маленьким.
Подскажите пожалуйста, какие параметры можно изменить, чтобы блок svg остался по прежнему 64 на 64, а рисунок увеличился(желательно занимал все пространство svg элемента)?

```html
 <svg
        version="1.1"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        width="64"
        height="64"
        viewbox="0 0 64 64">
        <defs>
            <filter id="blur" width="200%" height="200%">
                <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="3"/>
                <feOffset dx="0" dy="4" result="offsetblur"/>
                <feComponentTransfer>
                    <feFuncA type="linear" slope="0.05"/>
                </feComponentTransfer>
                <feMerge> 
                    <feMergeNode/>
                    <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/> 
                </feMerge>
            </filter>
            <style type="text/css"></style>
        </defs>
        <g filter="url(#blur)" id="day">
            <g transform="translate(32,32)">
                <g class="am-weather-sun am-weather-sun-shiny am-weather-easing-ease-in-out">
                    <g>
                        <line fill="none" stroke="orange" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="2" transform="translate(0,9)" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="3" />
                    </g>
                    <g transform="rotate(45)">
                        <line fill="none" stroke="orange" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="2" transform="translate(0,9)" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="3" />
                    </g>
                    <g transform="rotate(90)">
                        <line fill="none" stroke="orange" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="2" transform="translate(0,9)" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="3" />
                    </g>
                    <g transform="rotate(135)">
                        <line fill="none" stroke="orange" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="2" transform="translate(0,9)" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="3" />
                    </g>
                    <g transform="rotate(180)">
                        <line fill="none" stroke="orange" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="2" transform="translate(0,9)" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="3" />
                    </g>
                    <g transform="rotate(225)">
                        <line fill="none" stroke="orange" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="2" transform="translate(0,9)" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="3" />
                    </g>
                    <g transform="rotate(270)">
                        <line fill="none" stroke="orange" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="2" transform="translate(0,9)" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="3" />
                    </g>
                    <g transform="rotate(315)">
                        <line fill="none" stroke="orange" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="2" transform="translate(0,9)" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="3" />
                    </g>
                </g>
                <circle cx="0" cy="0" fill="orange" r="5" stroke="orange" stroke-width="2"/>
            </g>
        </g>
    </svg>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Размер картинки SVG и какое пространство она занимает внутри и сколько остается свободного пространства зависит от трех вещей: как она нарисована и от соотношения `viewport` (это width, height в шапке svg) и `viewBox`.

Масштабирование зависит от соотношения viewport / viewBox если = 1

1. viewport / viewBox = 1 Изменение размеров не происходит
2. viewport / viewBox >1 - увеличение изображения
3. viewport / viewBox < 1 - уменьшение изображения

Подробнее можно прочитать [здесь](http://svg-art.ru/?p=5)

Для настройки - подгонки размеров можно использовать стиль в шапке SVG, который покажет границы холста SVG `style="border:1px solid"`

```html
<svg
    version="1.1"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    width="64"
    height="64"
    viewBox="0 0 64 64" style="border:1px solid;">
    <defs>
        <filter id="blur" width="200%" height="200%">
            <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="3"/>
            <feOffset dx="0" dy="4" result="offsetblur"/>
            <feComponentTransfer>
                <feFuncA type="linear" slope="0.05"/>
            </feComponentTransfer>
            <feMerge> 
                <feMergeNode/>
                <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/> 
            </feMerge>
        </filter>
        <style type="text/css"></style>
    </defs>
    <g filter="url(#blur)" id="day">
        <g transform="translate(32,32)">
            <g class="am-weather-sun am-weather-sun-shiny am-weather-easing-ease-in-out">
                <g>
                    <line fill="none" stroke="orange" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="2" transform="translate(0,9)" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="3" />
                </g>
                <g transform="rotate(45)">
                    <line fill="none" stroke="orange" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="2" transform="translate(0,9)" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="3" />
                </g>
                <g transform="rotate(90)">
                    <line fill="none" stroke="orange" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="2" transform="translate(0,9)" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="3" />
                </g>
                <g transform="rotate(135)">
                    <line fill="none" stroke="orange" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="2" transform="translate(0,9)" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="3" />
                </g>
                <g transform="rotate(180)">
                    <line fill="none" stroke="orange" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="2" transform="translate(0,9)" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="3" />
                </g>
                <g transform="rotate(225)">
                    <line fill="none" stroke="orange" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="2" transform="translate(0,9)" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="3" />
                </g>
                <g transform="rotate(270)">
                    <line fill="none" stroke="orange" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="2" transform="translate(0,9)" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="3" />
                </g>
                <g transform="rotate(315)">
                    <line fill="none" stroke="orange" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="2" transform="translate(0,9)" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="3" />
                </g>
            </g>
            <circle cx="0" cy="0" fill="orange" r="5" stroke="orange" stroke-width="2"/>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Чтобы увеличить изображение нужно уменьшить `viewBox= "0 0 64 64"` до `viewbox="0 0 24 24"`
Изображение увеличится и сдвинется, необходимо вернуть его на середину

`<g transform="translate(12,12)">`

```html
<svg
    version="1.1"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    width="64"
    height="64"
    viewBox="0 0 24 24" style="border:1px solid">
    <defs>
        <filter id="blur" width="200%" height="200%">
            <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="3"/>
            <feOffset dx="0" dy="4" result="offsetblur"/>
            <feComponentTransfer>
                <feFuncA type="linear" slope="0.05"/>
            </feComponentTransfer>
            <feMerge> 
                <feMergeNode/>
                <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/> 
            </feMerge>
        </filter>
        <style type="text/css"></style>
    </defs>
    <g filter="url(#blur)" id="day">
        <g transform="translate(12,12)">
            <g class="am-weather-sun am-weather-sun-shiny am-weather-easing-ease-in-out">
                <g>
                    <line fill="none" stroke="orange" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="2" transform="translate(0,9)" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="3" />
                </g>
                <g transform="rotate(45)">
                    <line fill="none" stroke="orange" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="2" transform="translate(0,9)" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="3" />
                </g>
                <g transform="rotate(90)">
                    <line fill="none" stroke="orange" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="2" transform="translate(0,9)" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="3" />
                </g>
                <g transform="rotate(135)">
                    <line fill="none" stroke="orange" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="2" transform="translate(0,9)" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="3" />
                </g>
                <g transform="rotate(180)">
                    <line fill="none" stroke="orange" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="2" transform="translate(0,9)" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="3" />
                </g>
                <g transform="rotate(225)">
                    <line fill="none" stroke="orange" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="2" transform="translate(0,9)" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="3" />
                </g>
                <g transform="rotate(270)">
                    <line fill="none" stroke="orange" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="2" transform="translate(0,9)" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="3" />
                </g>
                <g transform="rotate(315)">
                    <line fill="none" stroke="orange" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="2" transform="translate(0,9)" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="3" />
                </g>
            </g>
            <circle cx="0" cy="0" fill="orange" r="5" stroke="orange" stroke-width="2"/>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Чтобы изображение было адаптивно и полностью заполняло родительский блок, необходимо удалить `width` `height` в шапке SVG и обернуть в `div`, размеры, которого указать в относительных единицах

```
<style>
.container {
width:5vw;
height:5vh;
   }
</style>
```

```html
<style>
.container {
width:5vw;
height:5vh;
           }
</style>
<div class="container">
<svg
    version="1.1"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    viewBox="0 0 28 28" >
    <defs>
        <filter id="blur" width="200%" height="200%">
            <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="3"/>
            <feOffset dx="0" dy="4" result="offsetblur"/>
            <feComponentTransfer>
                <feFuncA type="linear" slope="0.05"/>
            </feComponentTransfer>
            <feMerge> 
                <feMergeNode/>
                <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/> 
            </feMerge>
        </filter>
        <style type="text/css"></style>
    </defs>
    <g filter="url(#blur)" id="day">
        <g transform="translate(14,14)">
            <g class="am-weather-sun am-weather-sun-shiny am-weather-easing-ease-in-out">
                <g>
                    <line fill="none" stroke="orange" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="2" transform="translate(0,9)" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="3" />
                </g>
                <g transform="rotate(45)">
                    <line fill="none" stroke="orange" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="2" transform="translate(0,9)" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="3" />
                </g>
                <g transform="rotate(90)">
                    <line fill="none" stroke="orange" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="2" transform="translate(0,9)" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="3" />
                </g>
                <g transform="rotate(135)">
                    <line fill="none" stroke="orange" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="2" transform="translate(0,9)" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="3" />
                </g>
                <g transform="rotate(180)">
                    <line fill="none" stroke="orange" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="2" transform="translate(0,9)" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="3" />
                </g>
                <g transform="rotate(225)">
                    <line fill="none" stroke="orange" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="2" transform="translate(0,9)" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="3" />
                </g>
                <g transform="rotate(270)">
                    <line fill="none" stroke="orange" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="2" transform="translate(0,9)" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="3" />
                </g>
                <g transform="rotate(315)">
                    <line fill="none" stroke="orange" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="2" transform="translate(0,9)" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="3" />
                </g>
            </g>
            <circle cx="0" cy="0" fill="orange" r="5" stroke="orange" stroke-width="2"/>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Отлично, спасибо большое!

Comment: @EgorG и тебе спасибо за хорошо оформленный с кодом, интересный вопрос. Думай, пробуй над другими темами SVG, задавай ещё вопросы

Comment: Саша там во всех сниппетах ошибка

Comment: @MaximLensky если пишешь об ошибке, говори конкретно, где и что?

Comment: если не ошибаюсь viewBox с большой буквой B - я прав ?

Comment: @MaximLensky да, с большой, недосмотрел, копируя код с вопроса. Благодарю